# My Axios Post Code Is Changing The Post Data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm using the following code to send a post request to an API:

```
function postSales() {
  auth.then(result => {
    let token = result.access_token;

    const data = fs.readFileSync("./temp/converted.json", "utf-8");
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    // prettier-ignore
    parsedData.forEach((sale, i) =>
      limiter.removeTokens(1, function() {
        axios
          .post(
            `${baseUrl}/Sale.json`,
            { sale },
            {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                scope: `employee:all`
              }
            }
          )
          .then(res => console.log(res))
          .catch(err => console.error(err));
      })
    );
  });
}
```

I can see in the data that is posted, 'sale' is added at the beginning of my object, why would it do that? How can I prevent it?

Here is a sample of the data that is being posted:

```
data: '{"sale":{"shopID":"1","registerID":"1","employeeID":"1","completed":"true","referenceNumber":"10001000152","refernceNumberSource":"Opsuite","completeTime":"6/4/2017","TransactionQtySold":"2","TransactionTax":"1","TransactionTotalSales":"246.99","ItemSku":"JRY-EXT","ItemDescription":"EXPRESS GUN OIL DROPPER","Supplier":"John Rothery (Wholesale)Co Ltd","Department":"CHEMICAL & CLEANING","Category":"OILS & GREASES","Price":"5.99","Cost":"2.52","QtySold":"1","Tax":"1","TotalSales":"6.99","BinLocation":"D"}}',
```

The original data does not have the {sale: at the beginning and the api is refusing the post request because of this addition.

The post data should be formed as:

```
data: {"shopID":"1","registerID":"1","employeeID":"1","completed":"true","referenceNumber":"10001000152","refernceNumberSource":"Opsuite","completeTime":"6/4/2017","TransactionQtySold":"2","TransactionTax":"1","TransactionTotalSales":"246.99","ItemSku":"JRY-EXT","ItemDescription":"EXPRESS GUN OIL DROPPER","Supplier":"John Rothery (Wholesale)Co Ltd","Department":"CHEMICAL & CLEANING","Category":"OILS & GREASES","Price":"5.99","Cost":"2.52","QtySold":"1","Tax":"1","TotalSales":"6.99","BinLocation":"D"}}'
```

Comment: That's what `{ sale }` does... it's shorthand for `{ sale: sale }`. Try passing `sale` without wrapping it in `{ ... }`, ie `axios.post(url, sale, ...`

Comment: Ha, damn it. Thanks